# merging/concatenating arrays with different elements

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, vector

How to merge a mix of different elements (matlab style) in `numpy`?

`[array([ 0.]), 0.0, 0.0011627, 0.0, 2.69, 0.0, array([ 3.8269,  7.0184]), array([  4.4e-16,   2.1e+00])]`

(I tried `np.concatenate`, but obviously it only takes arrays as input).
Basically, I want to dynamically concatenate elements from a vector by indexing. I tried:

```
 V = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
 Y = np.array([7,8,9,10,11,12])

 Z = np.array([V[0:2],Y[0],V[3],Y[1:3],V[4:],Y[4:]])
```

It works, but has array elements inside. I just want a flat vector of numbers (Matlab style) as later I make a matrix (called RES) with a bunch of these vectors. Even a simple

```
 np.savetxt('TT',RES,fmt='%1.1e')
```

fails because it expects floats and not arrays inside.

Guess this should be simple. `np.hstack` does the job. But is there any other easy way to do Matlab style indexing & combining of vectors and scalars?

Answer (score 31):

You could use [np.r_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
In [32]: Z = np.r_[V[0:2],Y[0],V[3],Y[1:3],V[4:],Y[4:]]

In [33]: Z
Out[33]: array([ 1,  2,  7,  4,  8,  9,  5,  6, 11, 12])
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Such methods seem to be hidden though as I've not come across them (np.s_, np.r_, np.c_ ) anywhere, yet! Gracias!

Comment: Yes, this one is mentioned in the [NumPy Reference Guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/), but not the User Guide.

Comment: @nahsivar please accept the answer if it resolved your question