# What does np.r_ do (numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, merge

Following code is taken from [numpy function base on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a79d9d35c1b1582e5e0b8487f5dd414d15944f2c/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L207)

```
sa = sort(a[i:i+block])
n += np.r_[sa.searchsorted(bins[:-1], 'left'),
           sa.searchsorted(bins[-1], 'right')]
```

So I know that searchsorted finds the position in the array `sa` where the elements of `bins` would have to be inserted in order to keep `sa` sorted (`left` gives the index left of where we would insert the value and `right` the right index).
What I don't understand is the whole construction around it meaning what is

```
np.r_[array,array]
```

What is `np.r_`?

Comment: Just so the community can better focus any answers, is there anything in the [documentation for `np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) that isn't clear?

Comment: @AlexRiley As <some meta post I don't know how to find> states, asking questions that are answered in the docs is not only OK, but encouraged. As someone who googles for answers, I often skip docs and go to SO, because it is usually much clearer and more readable, with the best examples.

Comment: @Gulzar: Absolutely - but askers are still expected to do a basic search before creating their question. If the docs don't exist, or aren't helpful or clear, or the asker just wants a better explanation than those that currently exist on the Internet, then that's completely fine, but it's helpful to know this so that a baseline is established and answers can provide maximum value.

Comment: @AlexRiley yes, it lacks a bit of motivation, why would you use indexing rather than a function, I think that is unclear.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What it does is row-wise merging. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990345/merging-concatenating-arrays-with-different-elements/21990608#21990608) has some nice example:

```
>>>V = array([1,2,3,4,5,6 ])
>>>Y = array([7,8,9,10,11,12])
>>>np.r_[V[0:2],Y[0],V[3],Y[1:3],V[4:],Y[4:]]
array([ 1,  2,  7,  4,  8,  9,  5,  6, 11, 12])
```

Read more about it in this , and in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) of numpy.

Comment: Why not to use `np.hstack`?

Comment: @mrgloom you might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37751518/3523490)...

Answer (score 12):

```
numpy.r_[array[], array[]]
```

This is used to concatenate any number of array slices along row (first) axis. This is a simple way to create numpy arrays quickly and efficiently.

For instance, to create an array from two different arrays by selecting the elements of your choice, we'll have to assign the sliced values to a new varaible and use concatenation method to join them along an axis.

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b = np.arange(10,19).reshape(3,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

I want to create a new 2-D array, with 2*2 elements ([4,5,14,15]) then, I'll have to do the following,

```
>>> slided_a = a[1,1:3]
>>> sliced_b = b[1,1:3]
>>> new_array = np.concatenate((sliced_a, sliced_b), axis = 0)
```

As this is clearly an inefficient way because, as the number of elements that are to be included in the new array increases, the temporary variables that are assigned to store the sliced values increases.

This is where we use np.r_

```
>>> c = np.r_[a[1,1:3],b[1,1:3]]
array([ 4,  5, 14, 15])
```

Likewise, if we want to create a new array by stacking the sliced values in 2nd axis, we can use np.c_

```
>>> c = np.c_[a[1,1:3],b[1,1:3]]
array([[ 4, 14],
       [ 5, 15]])
```

Comment: You say that "as number of elements ...increases, the temp variables ... increases. This is where we use np.r_". But I don't see the difference between the line: `np.concatenate((a[1,1:3], b[1,1:3]), axis = 0)` and `np.r_[a[1,1:3],b[1,1:3]]`. Why should using `np.r_` be more efficient here? As I know the advantage of `np.r_` over `np.concatenate` is that `np.concatenate` only takes arrays as input.

Comment: Maybe because it is not a function. The docs say it takes slice expressions ...