# python why use numpy.r_ instead of concatenate

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

In which case using objects like numpy.r_ or numpy.c_ is better (more efficient, more suitable) than using functions like concatenate or vstack for example ?

I am trying to understand a code where the programmer wrote something like:

```
return np.r_[0.0, 1d_array, 0.0] == 2
```

where `1d_array` is an array whose values can be 0, 1 or 2.
Why not using `np.concatenate` (for example) instead ? Like :

```
return np.concatenate([[0.0], 1d_array, [0.0]]) == 2
```

It is more readable and apparently it does the same thing.

Comment: Just a notational convenience.  `np.r_[1:5, 3:7]` versus `np.concatenate(np.arange(....)`.  Same speed.  It all ends up as a `concatenate` call.

Comment: Full code is in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py.  `r_` is an `AxisConcatenator` object. Instructive reading.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`np.r_` is implemented in the `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` file.  This is pure Python code, with no special compiled stuff.  So it is not going to be any faster than the equivalent written with `concatenate`, `arange` and `linspace`.  It's useful only if the notation fits your way of thinking and your needs.

In your example it just saves converting the scalars to lists or arrays:

```
In [452]: np.r_[0.0, np.array([1,2,3,4]), 0.0]
Out[452]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.])
```

error with the same arguments:

```
In [453]: np.concatenate([0.0, np.array([1,2,3,4]), 0.0])
...
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

correct with the added []

```
In [454]: np.concatenate([[0.0], np.array([1,2,3,4]), [0.0]])
Out[454]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.])
```

`hstack` takes care of that by passing all arguments through `[atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]`:

```
In [455]: np.hstack([0.0, np.array([1,2,3,4]), 0.0])
Out[455]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.])
```

So at least in simple cases it is most similar to `hstack`.

But the real usefulness of `r_` comes when you want to use ranges

```
np.r_[0.0, 1:5, 0.0]
np.hstack([0.0, np.arange(1,5), 0.0])
np.r_[0.0, slice(1,5), 0.0]
```

`r_` lets you use the `:` syntax that is used in indexing.  That's because it is actually an instance of a class that has a `__getitem__` method.  `index_tricks` uses this programming trick several times.

They've thrown in other bells-n-whistles

Using an `imaginary` step, uses `np.linspace` to expand the slice rather than `np.arange`.

```
np.r_[-1:1:6j, [0]*3, 5, 6]
```

produces:

```
array([-1. , -0.6, -0.2,  0.2,  0.6,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  5. ,  6. ])
```

There are more details in the documentation.

I did some time tests for many slices in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37625115/901925

Answer (score 20):

I was also interested in this question and compared the speed of

```py
numpy.c_[a, a]
numpy.stack([a, a]).T
numpy.vstack([a, a]).T
numpy.column_stack([a, a])
numpy.concatenate([a[:,None], a[:,None]], axis=1)
```

which all do the same thing for any input vector `a`. Here's what I found (using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot)):

[image]

For smaller numbers, `numpy.concatenate` is the winner, for larger `stack`/`vstack`.

---

The plot was created with

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot

b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=np.random.rand,
    kernels=[
        lambda a: np.c_[a, a],
        lambda a: np.stack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.vstack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.column_stack([a, a]),
        lambda a: np.concatenate([a[:, None], a[:, None]], axis=1),
    ],
    labels=["c_", "stack", "vstack", "column_stack", "concat"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(22)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: came for `np._r` stayed for `perfplot` :)

Answer (score 6):

All the explanation you need:

https://sourceforge.net/p/numpy/mailman/message/13869535/

I found the most relevant part to be:

```
"""
For r_ and c_ I'm summarizing, but effectively they seem to be doing
something like:

r_[args]:
    concatenate( map(atleast_1d,args),axis=0 )

c_[args]:
    concatenate( map(atleast_1d,args),axis=1 )

c_ behaves almost exactly like hstack -- with the addition of range
literals being allowed.

r_ is most like vstack, but a little different since it effectively
uses atleast_1d, instead of atleast_2d.  So you have
>>> numpy.vstack((1,2,3,4))
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
but
>>> numpy.r_[1,2,3,4]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
"""
```

Comment: You should at least describe the content of that page, incase the hyperlink breaks.

Comment: @dodell fair enough

Comment: I think the comparison of `r_` and `c_` to `vstack` and `hstack` is misleading, even wrong.  In the case of `1,2,3,4` the 4 operations produce shapes (4,), (1,4), (4,1), (4,) respectively.  In this simple case `r_` and `hstack` produce the same thing, and `c_` and `vstack` are the transpose of each other.