# How can I perform two slices at the same time on a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that has a multi-index.  Here is a sample.

```
Subject     Date        x
00001-SHC-1 2016-09-30  5
00002-SHC-1 2016-09-30  6
00003-SHC-1 2016-09-30  5
00005-SHC-1 2016-09-30  5
00006-SHC-1 2016-09-30  3
```

Here, `Subject` and `Date` are my index.  I can slice the dataframe to get all observations in a particular date range using

`df.loc[(slice(None), slice('2016-09-01','2016-10-01') ),:]`

but what if I wanted to include observations in a second date range?  What if I wanted to slice all observations between `'2016-09-01'` and `'2016-09-30'` as well as all observations between `'2017-01-01'` and `'2017-01-31'`?

Comment: Instead of using slices explicitly, you could create index arrays, where the indices would be acquired by finding where the dates matched your criteria. So short answer is yes, it's very possible.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm using slices because they seem to be less verbose than other methods I can think of.  Could you give me an example of what you're thinking?

Comment: Use a boolean array instead of the date slice: Something like `((df.index < '...') & (df.index > '...')) | ((df.index > '...') & (df.index < '...'))`, where you set up that expression to give you the exact date ranges you need.

Comment: I'll leave it to someone that actually knows pandas well to make this into an actual answer, assuming this is a valid way to do it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh, I see what you're saying.  OK, I'll try that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yea, it worked.  It is pretty verbose, but I am ok with that for now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not a Pandas expert, but probably taking a look at [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) (a nice way to concatenate slices as well as zero-dimensional indices) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743843/python-why-use-numpy-r-instead-of-concatenate) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `query()` method:

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]:
                        x
Subject     Date
00001-SHC-1 2016-09-01  5
00002-SHC-1 2016-09-30  6
00003-SHC-1 2016-09-30  5
00005-SHC-1 2016-12-01  5
00006-SHC-1 2017-01-15  3
00007-SHC-1 2017-03-22  5

In [82]: df.query("'2016-09-01' <= Date <= '2016-09-30' or '2017-01-01' <= Date <= '2017-01-31'")
Out[82]:
                        x
Subject     Date
00001-SHC-1 2016-09-01  5
00002-SHC-1 2016-09-30  6
00003-SHC-1 2016-09-30  5
00006-SHC-1 2017-01-15  3
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an answer that does not use slices and works well enough for me.

```
dates = df.index.get_level_values(1)

mask =((dates>='2016-09-01')&(dates<='2016-09-30'))|((dates>='2017-01-01')&(dates<='2017-01-31'))

df.loc[

    (slice(None), mask),:
]
```