# np_r function with two values

Tags: python, numpy

I have found the following code:

```
x=0.3*np.random.randn(100,2)
x_train=np.r_[x+2,x-2]
```

In the first case x is an array of 100 rows and two columns in a format list of list, for what I see. In this case when I use size it returns 200. However, in the x_train part it is using np.r_. For what I know this instruction serves to concatenate arrays, so when I run size again it returns 400. However, I cannot get what does `x+2` and `x-2` perform in this case. For example, why in the first case is adding 2 and in the other case is subtracting 2?

I have read the documentation and still not get any clue.

Comment: Looks like it just pads out x with +2 and -2 on either side. More context would be needed though.

Comment: thanks @Chris this is the complete code https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html

Comment: @Little, just simplify the code : `x = np.arange(10); np.r_[x+2,x-2]`. Then with  `x = np.arange(10); x.shape= (5,2) ; np.r_[x+2,x-2]`. The concatenation will become clearer.

Comment: thank you @Demi-Lune, if you could put your comment as an answer would be great.

Comment: My comment was just to help you clarify the question (did you struggle to understand the concatenation? did  you wonder whether +2 -2 shifted the array or changed the values by +2 -2? ...).  The virtue of a MRVE: you usually find the answer by yourself :-)

Comment: For numpy users, saying `x.shape` is (100,2) is clearest.  `x.size` isn't that useful of a statistic.  `x_train` is (200,2), showing that the `r_` has joined two (100,2) arrays on the first axis.  The meaning of the '+-2' part comes from the broader context, since all it does it change values, not array shapes or sizes.

Comment: thank you @Demi-Lune I understand right away with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html) is showing how to find two separate classes in 2 dimensions. The code you are asking about generates random x&y coordinate data for those two separate classes

The purpose of `np.random.randn` is to generate 100 standard normally-distributed random x and y coordinate pairs (ie `x` is a 100x2 matrix). Side note, the .3 multiplier is probably used to decreased standard deviation for tighter clusters.

By adding 2 to `x` (ie add the value 2 to each element in `x`), they create a set of x and y coordinates that are closely scattered around (2,2) and by subtracting 2 from `x`, they create a set of x and y coordinates that are scattered around (-2,-2).

`np.r_` ,in this case, is the same as using `np.concatenate((x-2,x+2),0)` which creates a 200x2 array with 100 observations of x&y points scattered around (2,2) and 100 scattered around (-2,-2)

Comment: `np.r_` uses `np.concatenate`, and is actually slower, since it adds a function interpretation layer.  `np.r_` is most often used when the arguments are slices.  In this example, I think its use was a just stylistic preference.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the suggestion, I removed the misleading statement in the answer and eliminated my own misconceptions. Including [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743843/python-why-use-numpy-r-instead-of-concatenate#:~:text=on%20this%20post.-,np.,with%20concatenate%20%2C%20arange%20and%20linspace%20.) to the relevant question for reference.