# How to remerge the X_test and the y_test & the x_train and the y_train after splitting with sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, merge, split, scikit-learn

so i want to perform mean target encoding on Train & test Dataset after splitting them (using stratification) , and in order to do so ,  have to remerge them together.

how can i do that ? , any suggestion would be much appreciated ? , thank U.

```
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(R,
                                                target,
                                                test_size=0.25,
                                                random_state=7,
                                                stratify=target)  
   print("Number transactions X_train dataset: ", X_train.shape)
   print("Number transactions y_train dataset: ", y_train.shape)
   print("Number transactions X_test dataset: ", X_test.shape)
   print("Number transactions y_test dataset: ", y_test.shape)
```

Here's the output:

```
   Number transactions X_train dataset:  (37779, 89)
   Number transactions y_train dataset:  (37779,)
   Number transactions X_test dataset:  (12593, 89)
   Number transactions y_test dataset:  (12593,)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate your arrays row-wise:

```
X_combined = np.r_[X_train, X_test]
y_combined = np.r_[y_train, y_test]
```

You can see some additional depth in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597869/what-does-np-r-do-numpy) SO questions.