# What is the difference between using np.r_ and np.arange to create an array?

Tags: python, numpy

So I was made aware that the following two snippets produce arrays [0, 0.001, 0.002...]. Which of the two ways of creating arrays would be best practice and what are the differences? Why does np.r_[0:1:0.001] work if it is supposed to be used for row-wise concatenations?

```
 a = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
```

---

```
 b = np.r_[0:1:0.001]
```

I am also wondering why this prints false even though they are both type: numpy.ndarray.

```
if b is a:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

Comment: The `is` keyword returns true only when the two operands are the *same object in memory*. It is not an equality-of-value test. Also, generally speaking you can just print the boolean expression itself: `print(a == b)`, or, more appropriately since you're using numpy, `np.array_equal(a, b)`. See also the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L429) for `np.r_`.

Comment: Or [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), if you prefer.

Comment: You might also glean something from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597869/what-does-np-r-do-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange` and `np.linspace` are the basic functions for creating regularly spaced values.  Learn their differences.  Pay attention to `arange` warnings about fractional steps.

Novices often are bothered about floating point issues, such as when they view `np.arange(0,1,.1).tolist()`.

`np.r_` (and `np.c_`, `np.ogrid`, `np.mgrid`) uses indexing syntax to give you access to concatenation and ranges.  It isn't superior; it's just different, and may be convenient.

With `np.r_[0:1:0.001]` it does call `arange` just as you do.  with '0:1:11' it will use `linspace`.  And the concatenation functionality lets you do something like:

```
In [19]: np.r_[0:3, 3:5:5j]
Out[19]: array([0. , 1. , 2. , 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5, 5. ])
In [20]: np.concatenate((np.arange(3),np.linspace(3,5,5)))
Out[20]: array([0. , 1. , 2. , 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5, 5. ])
```

If `arange` (and `linspace`) does what you want, there's no need to use `np.r_`.

Answer (score 0):

`is` is not the right comparison tool. You would also get `False` with:

```
a = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
b = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)

a is b
# False
```

This simply means that the objects are not the same, not that their values is different

Use `numpy.allclose`:

```
a = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
b = np.r_[0:1:0.001]

np.allclose(a,b)
```

Output: `True`