# select specific rows from a large data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 790 rows. I want to create a new data frame that excludes rows from 300 to 400 and leave the rest.
I tried:

```
df.loc[[:300, 400:]]
df.iloc[[:300, 400:]]
df_new=df.drop(labels=range([300:400]), 
axis=0)
```

This does not work. How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `range` or [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for join indices:

```
df_new=df.drop(range(300,400)) 
df_new=df.iloc[np.r_[0:300, 400:len(df)]]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(20)})  
# print (df)
```

---

```
df1 = df.drop(labels=range(7,15))
print (df1)
     a
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19

df1 = df.iloc[np.r_[0:7, 15:len(df)]]
print (df1)
     a
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR - Sure, it is used for join ranges - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597869/what-does-np-r-do-numpy

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Also there is `np.c_`which I assume concatenates data sets column-wise.

Answer (score 2):

First select index you want to drop and then create a new df

```
i = df.iloc[299:400].index
new_df = df.drop(i)
```