# How access odd index elements and even index elements and merge them vertically

Tags: python, numpy

I've started learning `numpy` since yesterday.

**my AIM is**

Extract `odd index` elements from numpy array & `even index` elements from numpy and merge side by side vertically.

Let's say I have the array

```
mat = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

[image: see this picture]

What I've tried.

-->I've done transposing as I've to merge side by by side vertically.

`mat = np.transpose(mat)`

Which gives me

```
[[1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1]]
```

I've tried accessing odd index elements

`odd = mat[1::2] print(odd)`

Gives me

`[[1 1 0 0 0]`  ----> wrong...should be `[0,1,0,0,1]` right? I'm confused

`[0 0 1 0 0]]` --->wrong...Should be `[0,0,0,0,0]` right? Where these are coming from?

My final output should like like

```
[[0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1]]
```

Type - `np.nd array`

Comment: `mat[1::2]` selects odd `rows`  Rows 1 and 3 of the transposed array

Comment: `mat[::2]` even rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here alternate is the logic you can use.

```
 1. convert array to list
 2. Access nested list items based on mat[1::2] - odd & mat[::2] for even
 3. concat them using np.concat at `axis =0` vertically.
 4. Transpose them.
```

**Implementaion.**

```
mat = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
mat_list = mat.tolist() ##############Optional

l_odd = mat_list[1::2]
l_even= mat_list[::2]

mask = np.concatenate((l_odd, l_even), axis=0)
mask = np.transpose(mask)
print(mask)
```

**output #**

```
[[0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1]]
```

**Checking Type**

```
print(type(mask))
```

Gives

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Do you need the `to_list` step?

Comment: Even works without that...

Comment: so Slicing array & list works both same way? interesting..

Comment: Generally indexing with slices is the same for a list and the first dimension of an array.  But arrays allow you to index "columns" (other dimensions), and allow use of lists or arrays as indices.  So the notation is similar, but there's a lot more power with arrays.

Comment: Yes agree to @hpaulj..@Learningnoob array is faster than a list in slicing .This is because array have every elemnt same data type elements. In list it may contain other data types too. so list every time has to check with different data types makes significant time complexity diffrence when working on bigger data. Even you can remove `tolist()` line. You will get same output. Just mentioned to let you know slicing works same as in list and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
mat[np.r_[1:mat.shape[0]:2,:mat.shape[0]:2]].T
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Intermediate:

```
np.r_[1:mat.shape[0]:2,:mat.shape[0]:2]
```

output: `array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4])`

Comment: SImple!!!! +1..

Comment: Trying to understand `np.r_` @mozway...What is that...You have any refernce?

Comment: @Bhargav [What does np.r_ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597869/what-does-np-r-do-numpy) and of course [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

Comment: I'm too new to understand what you guys are talking..@mozway I don't understand logic..in this logic at what part even & odd numbered indexes are accesed?... Because you using `shape[0]:2` both same 2 times? Reference you provided is very high level to me...Based on this logic...I'm trying to apply for different array with different dimensions..

Comment: @Learningnoob that's why I provided the intermediate. `np.r_` enables to concatenate slices. Here I used two, the odd rows: `1:mat.shape[0]:2` and the even ones `:mat.shape[0]:2`

Answer (score 2):

While the selection of rows is straight forward, there are various ways of combining them.

```
In [244]: mat = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     ...:                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     ...:                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     ...:                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     ...:                 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

The odd rows:

```
In [245]: mat[1::2,:]     # or mat[1::2]
Out[245]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The even rows:

```
In [246]: mat[0::2,:]
Out[246]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Joining the rows verticallly (`np.vstack` can also be used):

```
In [247]: np.concatenate((mat[1::2,:], mat[0::2,:]), axis=0)
Out[247]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

But since you want columns - tranpose:

```
In [248]: np.concatenate((mat[1::2,:], mat[0::2,:]), axis=0).transpose()
Out[248]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

We could transpose the selections first:

```
np.concatenate((mat[1::2,:].T, mat[0::2,:].T), axis=1)
```

or transpose before indexing (note the change in the ':' slice position):

```
np.concatenate((mat.T[:,1::2], mat.T[:,0::2]), axis=1)
```

The `r_` in the other answer converts the slices into arrays and concatenates them, to make one row indexing array.  That's equally valid.

Comment: Such a valuble information +1!!