# Using start:stop:stepj outside of np.r_

Tags: python, numpy

I came across the [np.r_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990345/merging-concatenating-arrays-with-different-elements/21990608#21990608) in the reference guide of [the method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html?highlight=r_#numpy.r_) it is shown rather than concatenating an array using `np.linspace` we can use `start:stop:stepj`.

> In other words start:stop:stepj is interpreted as np.linspace(start,
> stop, step, endpoint=1)

Is this can be used outside of `np.r_` method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called slicing.

`list(range(10))[2:10:2]` would yield `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

Reference https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#slice

Answer (score 0):

The `start:stop:step` syntax only works in an indexing context (square brackets).

For functions we use

```
slice(start, stop, step)
range(start, stop, step)
np.arange(start, stop, step)
np.linspace(start, stop, count)  # not step
```

`np.r_` is an instance of a custom class that mimics indexing.  The class has a `__getitem__` method, so 'arguments' are passed to `np.r_` with the indexing syntax.

The code is implemented in `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py`.  The file name is significant - these are some interesting and clever tricks, but not essential to using `numpy`.

```
In [64]: np.r_[0:10:2, 0:10:5j]
Out[64]: array([ 0. ,  2. ,  4. ,  6. ,  8. ,  0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

This is the equivalent to do:

```
In [65]: np.arange(0,10,2)
Out[65]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
In [66]: np.linspace(0,10,5)
Out[66]: array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
In [67]: np.concatenate((_65,_66))
Out[67]: array([ 0. ,  2. ,  4. ,  6. ,  8. ,  0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

The interpreter actually translates the `[]` expression into this method call:

```
In [70]: np.r_.__getitem__((slice(0,10,2), slice(0,10,5j)))
Out[70]: array([ 0. ,  2. ,  4. ,  6. ,  8. ,  0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

`r_` looks at the elements of that tuple argument.  The first slice is used to run the `arange` call, the second (because of the complex `5j` value) is used to call `linspace`.  `np.r_` can also take an initial string argument.

While `np.r_` does some clever tricks, it does not add anything to python syntax. Nor does it do anything in compiled code.  It may give advanced programmers useful ideas, but nothing in it is essential for beginners.